# Adding multiple attachments in email with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The below code works for sending single attachment, how can I make the same for sending multiple attachments.?

My code:

Form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag mass_mail_reseller_path, :multipart => true, class: "new-mail-form form-horizontal" do%>
        <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="row form-group">
          <%= label_tag "attachment", 'Attachment:', class: "col-sm-1 control-label"%>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <%= file_field_tag "attachment",  multiple: true %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

my_controller.rb#action

```
def mail_reseller
    _from = params[:from]
    _to = get_resellers_mail_Ids(params[:to])
    _subject = params[:subject]
    _content = params[:body]
    if params[:attachment]
      _filename = params[:attachment].original_filename
      _file = params[:attachment].read
    end
    Resque.enqueue(ResellerWorker, _to, _from,  _subject, _content, _filename, _file)
    flash[:notice] = "Mail has been sent."
    redirect_to reseller_admin_path(:project_id => 'lead_tracking_reseller')
    # directory = "#{Rails.root}/files"
    # path = File.join(directory, _filename)
    # File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:attachment].read) }
  end
```

mailers/my_mailer.rb

```
def mass_mail_resellers _to, _from, _subject, _content, _filename, _file
    attachments[_filename] = _file if (_filename && _file)
    @mail_body = _content
    mail from: _from,
         to: _to,
         bcc: 'jam@company.com',
         subject: _subject
  end

model/resller.rb
class Reseller < User
  has_many :settlements
  belongs_to :account_manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'account_manager_id'
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plans
  has_many :attachments
end
```

## ResellerWorker code.

reseller_worker.rb

```
class ResellerWorker
  @queue = :reseller_mail_queue
  include Redmine::I18n

  def self.perform(_to, _from, _subject, _content, _filename, _file)
    _to.each do |_reseller|
      ResellerMailer.mass_mail_resellers(_reseller, _from, _subject, _content, _filename, _file).deliver
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You need to dig into what you're getting from `params[:attachment]`.  Assuming your form handles multiple file uploads correctly, changing your controller could just be a matter of iterating through `param[:attachment].keys.each ...`

Comment: You need to try out some stuff as per your understanding and then post the errors, if you face any. Your whole code is assuming single attachment. For answering your question is like re-writing whole code for you

Comment: The OP provided his code - similiar to mine - so if it is "re-writing whole code" to add another attachment to an email, then I guess there is another completely separate procedure to do this?  I can find no information about how to add 2+ attachments other than this one SO post.  As is, I am sending multiple emails as a workaround.  If action-mailer does not have the ability to send multiple attachments, please advise, and I will let my client know it is a limitation in the RoR framework.